# How to get the anchor property of a URL of an iframe using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I am trying to get the anchor part of a URL from an iFrame using javascript or jQuery.

eg.

```
<iframe id="theIFrame" src="location.html#anchorHere"></iframe>
```

if I use the src attribute I don't get the hash.

eg.

`$('#theIFrame').attr('src')` will return 'location.html'

How do I get the hash?

thank you,
George

Comment: $('#theIFrame').attr('src').split('#')[1]

Answer (score 3):

To get everything after the `#` mark, you can try the following:

```
var href = $("#theIFrame").attr("href");
var splitHref = href.split("#");
alert(splitHref[1]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j8JRx/)**

**EDIT**

OP was was changed from:

```
<iframe id="theIFrame" href="location.html#anchorHere"></iframe>
```

to:

```
<iframe id="theIFrame" src="location.html#anchorHere"></iframe>
```

so you would need to change the code to:

```
var href = $("#theIFrame").attr("src");
var splitHref = href.split("#");
alert(splitHref[1]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j8JRx/1/)**

**Or**, as @Pushpesh has recently noted in the comments section, a more condensed version would be:

```
$('#theIFrame').attr('src').split('#')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$('#theIFrame').attr('src').text()
```

or try

```
$('#theIFrame').attr('href').split('#')[1]
```

Comment: You are just getting the href with this and not the hash.

Comment: I thought that he wants the entire "href" if he asks for hash then i edit it

Comment: Direct quote from question: `How do I get the hash?`

Comment: hash means hw can i know whether it is with the hash or itself

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't working for me. $('#theIFrame').attr('src') just brings back the src attribute of the iframe.
What I want is what the anchor id that has been clicked from within the iframe.

so....
1. the iframe is loaded with a document.
2. the document is full of anchor tags linking to within the document itself. I want the current #hash of the last anchor that was clicked.

Anyone help?
cheers,
George

Comment: Actually here is how I did it....



document.getElementById("theIFrame").contentWindow.location.href